# Generic factory/service to avoid duplicate code in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, duplicates, refactoring, factory

So i have a set of factories which look quite similar. I want to perhaps make a generic function which will reduce duplicate code.

Example of code:

```
.factory('neQueryService', function ($http, $resource, constants) {
return $resource(constants.GEODATA_QUERY, {},
  {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      transformResponse: function(data, headers, status){
        var response = {};
        response.data = data;
        response.headers = headers();
        response.status = status;
        return response;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

And

```
.factory('neTaskService', function ($http, $resource, constants) {
return $resource(constants.GEODATA_TASK, {},
  {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      transformResponse: function(data, headers, status){
        var response = {};
        response.data = data;
        response.headers = headers();
        response.status = status;
        return response;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

As you can see, everything from the "get" down to "return" i identical among the factories. Is there a smart "best practice" way of maybe putting that part into a separate function and just refer to that in all factories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `value()` provider for this since it doesn't have any external dependencies:

```
.value('resourceConfig', {
    get: {
      method: 'GET',
      transformResponse: function(data, headers, status){
        var response = {};
        response.data = data;
        response.headers = headers();
        response.status = status;
        return response;
      }
    }
});

.factory('neQueryService', function ($http, $resource, constants, resourceConfig) {
    return $resource(constants.GEODATA_QUERY, {}, resourceConfig);
});

.factory('neTaskService', function ($http, $resource, constants, resourceConfig) {
    return $resource(constants.GEODATA_TASK, {}, resourceConfig);
});
```

Or you could go a step further and factor out a factory for creating your resources:

```
.factory('prepareResource', function ($resource) {
    return function (query) {
        return $resource(query, {}, {
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function(data, headers, status){
                    var response = {};
                    response.data = data;
                    response.headers = headers();
                    response.status = status;
                    return response;
                }
           }
       });
   };
});

.factory('neQueryService', function (prepareResource, constants) {
    return prepareResource(constants.GEODATA_QUERY);
});

.factory('neTaskService', function (prepareResource, constants) {
    return prepareResource(constants.GEODATA_TASK);
});
```

Comment: Excellent suggestions. I used the last one. However, still wondering how one knows which one is "best practice" sort of say? Any words on this?

Comment: @Amir I think that's more a matter of preference than anything. I would prefer the second one since it factors out the largest amount of code, but if, for example, you didn't always want to build resources that way and wanted to sometimes call `$resource(constants.GEODATA_QUERY, somethingSpecificToThisResource, resourceConfig)`, then the first option would be better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using ES6 modules, just move common code into another factory:

```
.factory('GetQuery', function () {
  return {
    method: 'GET',
    transformResponse: function(data, headers, status){
      var response = {};
      response.data = data;
      response.headers = headers();
      response.status = status;
      return response;
    }
  });

.factory('neQueryService', function ($http, $resource, constants, GetQuery) {
  return $resource(constants.GEODATA_QUERY, {},
    {
      get: GetQuery
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, configure the default action in $resourceProvider:

```
app.config(function($resourceProvider) {
    $resourceProvider.defaults.get = {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function(data, headers, status){
          var response = {};
          response.data = data;
          response.headers = headers();
          response.status = status;
          return response;
        }
     };
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $resourceProvider API Reference.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/provider/$resourceProvider)